# Redis bulk action restore RDB - RDB Path issue

Tags: docker, redis, redisinsights

I'm new to Redis Cache and I just created a local database in which I'm trying to restore an export from a RDB file.

I'm using Redis Insight as a client, running via docker, with volumes.
I identified the bulk_operation folder, copied the .rdb file in there and now from the Redis Insight interface I'm trying to restore the RDB using bulk actions.
However the path I'm providing results in "File not found" and I can't get to the expected format.

```
./db/bulk_operation/export-7b85c642-3bfc-4904-b0c0-81c84aae6748.rdb
```

The `/DB` is mounted to my local persistence folder.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My trial wasn't far from the truth, the expected format was `/db/bulk_operation/export-7b85c642-3bfc-4904-b0c0-81c84aae6748.rdb`  - note the missing dot at the beginning.

The fact that RedisInsight also randomly gives errors did not help, on the first two tries it failed, then randomly it worked.

So don't give up on the first fail :)